# How to prevent de-duplication of a particular combination of entries in an array in python?

Tags: python

I am writing a piece of code in python where i am working with arrays.
I am loading data row-wise from a csv into my array.
The data looks somewhat like this:

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh
111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888
abb,acc,add,ddd,vvv,bxc,nyc,hhh
```

now in the first and third rows even though the rows do not match exactly, my columns of interest are column 4 and column 8 i.e if two rows have same data in these columns as shown in the example, these should be treated as duplicate entries and my array should have only the first and second rows and should not have the third row.

```
result=[]
for file in input_file:
    f=open(file,'r')
    reader = csv.reader(f, quotechar='"')#read csv 
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            #do some operations on the elements of row
                if(row[3] and row[7] not in result):#
                    result.append(row)#load result in array
                else:
                    continue
```

I expect the result array to be like this

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh
111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888
```

whereas the output is

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh
111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888
abb,acc,add,ddd,vvv,bxc,nyc,hhh
```

Comment: I would create two empty `set`s (e.g. `set3` and `set7`) and compare respective column values with those sets. I would then add the row values to the sets if I have decided to append the row to my `result`.

Comment: @Selcuk i think i get you but could you please elaborate on your answer? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you want to examine for dups is a pair of two values (columns 3 and 7 using zero based numbering). A set named `seen` is often used for that purpose. The basic idea is:

```
seen = set()
for row in reader:
    data = (row[3], row[7])
    if data in set:
        continue
    set.add(data)
    # process row
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only catch if both columns are duplicates?

Comment: @Selcuk Yes, I think that is what the OP wants: _"if two rows have same data in these columns ..., these should be treated as duplicate entries ..."_

Comment: @Selcuk yes this is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

1: Load your csv using pands
2: take the data only for interested column
3: user pd.drop_duplicates()

refer link
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-drop_duplicates/][1]

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("YOUR_FILE_NAME")
df.drop_duplicates(subset['first_intrested_column','second_intrested_column'],keep
=False, inplace=True)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but is it a must that i need column names for using this particular solution?any way where i can mention the column numbers?

Comment: you can convert your data into by pandas by using " df =pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 'c'], [7, 8, 9]])))  . it will assign the default column name to your data i.e. 0,1,2,3 and so on

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is the test for duplicates is incorrect.
Here's a version I think does it correctly:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
from pprint import pprint, pformat

input_file = ['''
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh
111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888
abb,acc,add,ddd,vvv,bxc,nyc,hhh
''',]

result=[]
for file in input_file:
#    f=open(file,'r')
    f = StringIO(file)
    reader = csv.reader(f, quotechar='"')  # read csv
    for row in reader:
        if row and not any((row[3] == r[3] and row[7] == r[7]) for r in result):
            result.append(row)  # load result in array

pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh'],
 ['111', '222', '333', '444', '555', '666', '777', '888']]
```